# Comma and Parse Errors in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to learn React Native using tutorials I'm finding on YouTube and such. However it seems like the syntax has changed greatly since the release of these tuts.

Currently I'm getting a `requireTrailingComma: Missing comma before closing curly brace` error. But when I place a comma before the curly brace, it them tells me `parseError Unexpected token`.

ViewContainer.js Code:

```
'use strict'
import { Component, View } from 'react-native';

class ViewContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = React.Stylesheet.create({

  viewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  } <TIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING THE ERROR>

});

module.exports = ViewContainer;
```

index.ios.js Code:

```
'use strict'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import ViewContainer from './app/components/ViewContainer';

class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <Text>{'Hello from inside ViewContainer'}</Text>
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project', () => Project);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html according to this, you're missing the trailing comma after: `alignItems: 'stretch',
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says all, just put in a trailing comma after the curly brace.

```
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  }
```

to

```
 alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
```

or

```
  alignItems: 'stretch' 
}
```

Comment: Ok so the error actually confused me. It said to place the comma before the curly brace. But thanks for that clarification. It removed the error from the file and everything seems to be fine. I do have another error, but I think I need to crete another question for that.